# Can't compile a self programmed function on ModelSim

Tags: vhdl

I got a problem with compiling a VHDL code, I get a error when at :

use bin2bcd.all;

by the way the code works on ISE by not on ModelSIm any Idea ???!! !
thanks in advance.

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all; 
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; 
library bin2bcd; 
use bin2bcd.all;
```

and bin2bcd is :

```
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all; 
package bin2bcd is 
function to_bcd ( bin : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) ) return std_logic_vector; 
end bin2bcd;
```

Comment: You need to give us a "VETSMOD":http://www.sigasi.com/vetsmod code example. With your single line of code, we have no clue what's wrong.
ModelSim is considered to be the oracle of legal VHDL. ISE might be too relaxed for this situation.

Comment: sorry  philipps, it's just the start of my programm;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use bin2bcd.all;

the last line doesn't work :(

Comment: What error message is ModelSim giving you? If it doesn't know about the bin2bcd package is it in a different library? In which case you should have a line saying "library <my_package_library_name>" followed by "use <my_package_library_name>.<my_package_name>.all" on a new line, just like you do for the IEEE library.

Comment: hey Peter, well it didn't work I tried to use :

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
library bin2bcd;
use bin2bcd.all;

and bin2bcd is :



library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

package bin2bcd is

  function to_bcd  ( bin : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) ) return std_logic_vector;

end bin2bcd;


any Idea ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile `bin2bcd`, it goes into the `work` library (unless youv'e made the compiler do something else).

This means you need to do:

`use work.bin2bcd.all`

Looking at this:

```
library bin2bcd; 
use bin2bcd.all;
```

you may actually have compiled a package called `bin2bcd` into a library called `bin2bcd`.

in which case you need to do this

```
library bin2bcd; 
use bin2bcd.bin2bcd.all;
```